# Converting Java to C++: Templates vs. Generics

Tags: java, c++

I'm a C++ newb trying to convert Java code to C++, and I think I'm doing something wrong. The Java code is the following:

```
class Container<T> {
    public T internal;
    public static Container lastInstance;
    Container(T value){
        internal = value;
        lastInstance = this;
    }
}

class test2 {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        Container<String> str = new Container<String>("moo");
        Container<Integer> myint = new Container<Integer>(777);
        System.out.println("Last Instance: " + str.lastInstance.internal);
    }
}
```

And I have the following so far for C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class Container {
public:
  T internal;
  static Container<T> *lastInstance;

  Container(T val){
    internal = val;
    lastInstance = this;
  };
};

int main(){

  Container<int> *myint = new Container<int>(4);
  Container<string> *str = new Container<string>("hello");
  cout << myint->lastInstance->internal << endl;
  cout << str->lastInstance->internal << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: More on the error.
The error is indeed a linking error. Here's the full message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Container<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::lastInstance", referenced from:
  _main in template-d68cfa.o
  Container<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::Container(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in template-d68cfa.o
"Container<int>::lastInstance", referenced from:
  _main in template-d68cfa.o
  Container<int>::Container(int) in template-d68cfa.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

EDIT2: Compiling using g++

Comment: I know. But I thought you guys might be able to help, and as I said, I'm a C++ newb ..

Comment: That looks like a linking error, not a compiler error. You need to specify more information for this question.  Include your compile command, and which OS/compiler you're using.

Comment: I edited the body of the linking error into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A premise: generally speaking, comparing Java generics and C++ templates is like comparing apples with oranges. They are totally different semantically and they work in a complete different way.

So trying to translate one into another is not a good idea unless you know why and how they differ.

Regarding your specific problem, it's given by the fact that you have a `static` member variable. A `static` member variable in C++ requires a definition outside the class declaration, this because you must tell the compiler where this static variable will be stored.

So basically to fix you problem you need to add the definition for `lastInstance`:

```
template<typename T> Container<T>* Container<T>::lastInstance;
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was trying to explore by playing around with C++ templates and Java generics, I want to see what the C++ version will output. Thanks pal!